# SAS ENTERPRISE GUIDE - COMPUTED COLUMN

Tags: sas, calculated-columns, datefield, enterprise-guide

I have created a column with the following formula

```
IFN(t1.COVEFFDATE<'01APR2014'D, '01APR2014'D, t1.COVEFFDATE)
```

t1.COVEFFDATE is a date field in the table. I have put a DATE9. format to my computed column, however it's producing ********* in my query data set. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: I thought when I read your title that your CAPS LOCK must be broken, but I see from your question text that it isn't. Is there a particular reason you're SHOUTING at us? It won't get you an answer any more quickly here.

Comment: Huh? Sometimes people capitalize differently. Not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, figured it out. COVEFFDATE is a date/time field so changed the format of the computed column to DTDATE9. and the formula to the computed column to:

```
IFN(t1.COVEFFDATE<'01APR2014:00:00:00'DT, '01APR2014:00:00:00'DT, t1.COVEFFDATE)
```

Comment: FYI, another way to make it work is to use the `datepart` function to return just the date part of your variable. e.g. `datepart(t1.COVEFFDATE)<'01APR2014'D`.